# Are the breakdown voltages of silicon dioxide and silicone dioxide the same?

Tags: electricity, voltage, material-science, elements, polymers

Silicon dioxide has a breakdown voltage of $> 10$ MV/cm [[1]](https://www.slideshare.net/TuanLinh2263/breakdown-voltage-of-silicon-dioxide). However, I am unable to find any information about the breakdown voltage of *silicone* dioxide. Since silicone contains oxygen (and sometimes carbon and hydrogen) in addition to silicon, I would guess that they are not identical. Are they at least in the same ballpark? How can I find more information about silicone dioxide's breakdown voltage?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this mysterious silicon**e** dioxide? I'm a chemist and have never heard of it...

Comment: The simple answer is, since they are wildly different materials (depending on just what you mean by silicone dioxide), their breakdown will be different.

Comment: @Gert I found a reference here: https://sci-hub.se/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7538348#

Comment: @JonCuster Here is a reference for silicone dioxide. This is not exactly my area and I am unsure whether they (silicon/silicone dioxide) are interchangeable or if one is a misspelling, since I see both spellings referred to as the same thing on some websites. https://sci-hub.se/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7538348#

Comment: @JonCuster Here is an example of Silicon Dioxide (SIO2) being referred to as "Silicone Dioxide" https://www.cericom.de/en/glossary/silicon-dioxide/

Comment: Sources that use spelling like *silicone di oxide* cannot be trusted. *Silicone dioxide* is also a misspelling. Chemically there is no such thing, let me assure you.

Comment: The Cericom doc is very clearly also a misspelling. Case closed, AFAIC.

Comment: I can't write an answer just for that. The two breakdown voltages shall be the same simply because silicone dioxide is misspelled silicon dioxide. If you search for the breakdown voltage of silicones, that is another story.